# How can I fill predefined text template with variables from currently selected row and outup result in another selectable text field?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

[here's what it would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bS5e.png)

I'm trying to generate text like mail merge based on which row is currently selected.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried inserting floating frames, tried to reference columns but could not get it to work

Comment: What about this: Put the template text into a cell (not a frame). Then use a macro to get the text, replace the template fields and create the frame with the replaced text.

Comment: For further help, edit the question to show example code you've tried so far. That may give us a better idea of what you want to do.